# How to loop through tables from SQL in c# without hardcoding

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm creating a desktop application. I have 3 table (part time employees table, full time employees table and department table). The ID on department table is the foreign key.

I have created a connection string in my class. I'm trying to loop through the tables to get all departments that are assigned to employees, if a department is not assigned (delete it). I have the code in sql, but I want it in c#. Below is the sql code.

```
    SELECT  DepartmentName, DepartmentAddress
    FROM Department 
    WHERE ID IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(ID) 
    FROM 
    PartTimeEmployees
    );
```

Comment: What are you using to connect to database and read data? There are different ways of doing that

Comment: I did not understand you want to delete the department or employee ?

Comment: SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection();
        public DataSet SqlTable = new DataSet();
        public ProjectConnection()
        {
            SqlConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Employee"].ConnectionString;

        }
        public void retrieveData( string command)
        {
            try
            {
               
            }
            catch (Exception )
            {
                
            }
            finally
            {
                SqlConn.Close();

Comment: @AvinashKumar. I'm trying to delete the department if it is not assigned to an employee.

Comment: Can you post your c# code and try to explain where in the code you need help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If deleting department not in part time employees table or full time employees table then you can get the department list as -

```
var departmentToDelete = departments.Where(d => !PartTimeEmployees.Any(emp => emp.DepartmentId == d.Id) && !FullTimeEmployees.Any(emp => emp.DepartmentId == d.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to `DELETE` departments that don't have a related employee, you can use an `EXISTS`:

```sql
DELETE D
FROM dbo.Department D
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM dbo.Employee E
                 WHERE E.DepartmentID = D.ID);
```

There's no need to go any kind of "looping", as SQL is *far* better at doing these operations in a set-based way.